# Firebase 3.0 throws cross-origin error when bundled with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack, babeljs

I'm running into an issue with Firebase 3.0.3, where it throws the following error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at Error (native)
at derez (<anonymous>:995:515)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208)
at derez (<anonymous>:1001:208) 

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3000" from accessing a frame with origin "https://falkor.firebaseapp.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

My stack uses React 15.1.0, Redux 3.5.2, Babel-Core 6.9.0 and webpack 1.13.1.

Here are the important parts:

```
// ./src/constants/index.js

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
firebase.initializeApp(JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG));

export const ref = firebase.database().ref();
export const auth = firebase.auth();




// ./src/actions/auth.js

import * as actions from './';
import { ref, auth } from '../constants';

export const loadAuth = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { subscribed } = getState().firebase;
    if (subscribed.indexOf('auth') < 0) {
      dispatch(actions.fbaseSubscribed('auth'));
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          dispatch(loadMe(user.uid));
          dispatch(actions.auth(user));
        }
      });
    }
  };

const serialize = data => ({ [data.key]: data.val() });

export const loadMe = (uid) =>
  (dispatch, getStore) => {
    const { subscribed } = getStore().firebase;
    if (subscribed.indexOf('me') < 0) {
      dispatch(actions.fbaseSubscribed('me'));
      const item = ref.child('teamMembers').child(uid);

      item.on('child_added',   data => dispatch(actions.me(serialize(data))));
      item.on('child_changed', data => dispatch(actions.me(serialize(data))));
      item.on('child_removed', data => dispatch(actions.me(serialize(data))));
    }
  };

export const login = ({email, password}) =>
  () => {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(err => console.error(err));
  };

export const renewSession = token =>
  () => {
    auth.signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(err => console.error(err));
  };
```

When I try the [quickstart app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js) I don't run into any issues with the firebase config being initialized in the head of the page. I only run into this issue when I install the module with NPM and bundle it with webpack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been scratching my head for a few hours now.

Comment: I have the same issue with the same stack, and also quickstart app do not reproduce the problem

Comment: I just realize that using the dist version of my application the error not occurs. It seems that webpack-devserver is causing the problem

Comment: It seems that it could be related to webpack-dev-middleware

Comment: I experience the same problem when I am running my dist code, so I don't think it is an issue with `webpack-server`

Comment: I found that in my code there was an error that I was trying to dispatch an action passing user as parameter but user, if I remove user from the action I don't get the error. It seems that the error happens when another error happens in the "then" statement of firebase promise. Solving that it works ok for me even with auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see your entire code, but as it worked for me, try to not dispatch an action with entire user

```
export const loadAuth = () =>
  (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { subscribed } = getState().firebase;
    if (subscribed.indexOf('auth') < 0) {
      dispatch(actions.fbaseSubscribed('auth'));
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          dispatch(loadMe(user.uid));
          //dispatch(actions.auth(user)); // not dispatch the entire user. When I changed this my code worked
          dispatch(actions.auth(user.email));
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

**Update 1**

I made this simple transform function to parse data from Firebase user object:  https://gist.github.com/douglascorrea/003ae6a6b11f19c97d6ee5b28d0d9eef

And also, if you want more information about this issue you can follow up this thread in Firebase group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/Lp6I9uS0PAo/AbHwr_03DwAJ

**Update 2**
I created a Firebase 3.0 starter with React Redux.

You can take a look at: [Firebase 3.0 starter with React Redux](https://github.com/douglascorrea/react-hot-redux-firebase-starter)

---

Comment: I found this same thing on Thursday and was going to write an answer for it. Thank you for getting to it though! I now pull uid, refreshToken, photoUrl and send those to my reducer, and the error goes away. Seems that the reducer doesn't like something in the user object and won't store it. But like you said in a different comment, the error came through the promise which was misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but using ES6 import statement, you should use:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

When using ES5 require() its:

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
```

Note that the Firebase npm package has both browser and node versions in it (see the 'browser' and 'main' entry points, respectively).

Be sure you have the latest Firebase installed  (3.0.3) - an early version had a bug in the way we exported the firebase namespace in Browserify/WebPack.

Comment: I was using firebase 3.0.2, I've updated to 3.0.3 and changed my import to `import * as firebase from 'firebase'` and am getting the same issues. I'll see if I can put together a small sample app that reproduces the same thing and link to it here.

Comment: Thanks - I tried reproducing this with webpack and my code is working fine - so there's some difference I'm missing here.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.3 and used the import * and still happens. And when I build the project and use express to serve it not happens. It seems to be related to webpack-dev-server or webpack-dev-middleware

Comment: @mckoss I just removed auth from my application and changed my rules to not require auth and I no longer receive the error. Sorry still working on another application for you, just have to find time to get it done. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: @AJW Thanks for the hint on webpack-dev-server.  I think what is happening is that it is loading the node.js firebase code, and serving it to a browser.  Our package.json has two distinct entrypoints, depending on which environment you're using:

  "main": "firebase-node.js",
  "browser": "firebase-browser.js",

Comment: I couldn't repo just using webpack-dev-server afterall.  So maybe webpack-dev-middleware is the culprit?

Comment: As I said in the comment above it worked for me changing my code: https://gist.github.com/douglascorrea/fe5008490da734efd5cca771ab400740

Comment: Is that an issue with the Firebase lib though? Because it shouldn't throw a CORs error when trying to destructure a property.. why would these be related?